# Triples in the field with 9 elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

I am struggling with the following question:

Let $\mathbb{F}_9$ be the field with nine elements. How many triples $a,b,c$ of elements in $\mathbb{F}_9$ are there, such that $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ ?

I suppose the brute force way is to go through all combinations $a,b,c$ of elements in $\mathbb{F}_9$, and check algebraically which ones satisfy the given equation  $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$. However, with $9$ lements in the field, this gives $9^3$ possible triples, which is way too many to check.

How can I solve this without using brute force ?

Another idea I had is to identity $\mathbb{F}_9$ with the quotient $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/(x^2 + x + 2)$, where $(x^2 + x + 2)$ is the ideal generated by the polynomial $x^2 + x + 2$, which is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$. However, this still gives $9^3$ polynomials corresponding to triples $a,b,c$ in $\mathbb{F}_9$, again giving too many possibilities to check by brute force whether the equation $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ is satisfied.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found brute force was not as bad as anticipated.

Say $\mathbb F_9=\mathbb Z_3[i]$, where $i^2=2$.

The elements of $\mathbb F_9$ are then $0, 1, 2, i, 1+i, 2+i, 2i, 1+2i, $ and $2+2i$.

Their squares are $0, 1, 2, i,$ and $2i$.  The non-squares are $1+i, 2+i, 1+2i$, and $2+2i$.

So there are five choices for $a^2$ and five choices for $b^2$.

The following seventeen $(a^2,b^2)$ pairs satisfy $a^2+b^2=c^2$ for some $c\in\mathbb F_9$:

$(0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (0,i), (0,2i), (1,0), (2,0), $

$(i,0), (2i, 0), (1,1), (1, 2), (2,1), (2,2), (i,i), (i, 2i), (2i, i), $ and $(2i, 2i)$.

The following eight $(a^2,b^2)$ pairs do not satisfy $a^2+b^2= c^2$ for some $c\in\mathbb F_9$:

$(1,i), (1,2i), (i,1), (2i,1), (2,i), (i,2), (2,2i), (2i,2)$.

Comment: It should be noted that each square except $0$ has two square roots.

Comment: $(0,0)$ corresponds to one $(a,b)$ pair; $(0,x)$ or $(x,0)$ with $x\ne0$ corresponds to two $(a,b)$ pairs; and $(x,y)$ with $xy\ne0$ corresponds to four $(a,b)$ pairs, so the seventeen $(a^2,b^2)$ pairs that sum to a square correspond to forty-nine $(a,b)$ pairs; as for the eight pairs that do not, they correspond to thirty-two $(a,b)$ pairs (the total number of pairs is $49+32=81$ as would be expected for $9$ choices for $a$ and $9$ for $b$